# How to change Month View to Week View vice versa for JTAppleCalendar

Tags: swift3, jtapplecalendar

Hi newBiew in JTAppleCalendar. 
I follow this link for JTAppleCalendar. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQNotydm58s&index=6&list=PLpqJf39XekqyUG7dxcqGO0JNprryysv9Q

I have this Problem:

How to I show calendar when user click a button to change monthView to WeekView or from week View to month View

How to I change the calendar size programmatically for CalendarView and mainStack as they have  constrains?
I believe I need to handle configureCalendar as below but how to change programmatically month view to week view vice versa.
I have a stack (Call it mainStack) which used to contain CalendarView

Layout for the Calendar view :

```
@IBOutlet weak var CalendarView : JTAppleCalendarView!<br/>
@IBOutlet weak var mainStack: UIStackView!<br/>


extension MyCalendar: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource, JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate {

    func configureCalendar( _ calendar:JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {

        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
        formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
        formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

        let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 01")!
        let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2027 12 31")!        

        //-- how to set these "

       1) Full calendar view

        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate : startDate, endDate: endDate)          
        return parameters


       2) for week view
        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate : startDate, endDate: endDate, numberOfRows:1)      

        return parameters

    }


  func calendar( _ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell{


        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text

        configureCell(cell:cell, cellState: cellState)

        return cell

    }


    //------------ selected item

    func calendar( _ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell:JTAppleCell?, cellState:CellState){

        configureCell(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)     

    }


    func calendar( _ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didDeselectDate date: Date, cell:JTAppleCell?, cellState:CellState){

              configureCell(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)

    }

   func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didScrollToDateSegmentWith visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo) {

       setupCalendarView(dateSegment: visibleDates)

    }

}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: any1 can help. Thanks

Comment: does this example here help? https://github.com/patchthecode/WLAppleCalendar   You can see that his calendar changes size by one row. Maybe you can use his example but instead change the size by one than one row. His calendar uses JTApplecalendar library

Comment: @patchthecode, I need one row for caledar. Ontop this one row, I have one row with Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat.  Please help.

Comment: Did you get the solution to change Month View to Week View?

Comment: didnt get a notification for this. I hope it has been solved now.

Answer (score 0):

So the plan is:

You have a variable for the number of rows.

In a monthView mode, it has 6 rows.

In a weekView mode, it has 1 row.

So when you want to change the mode you change numberOfRows and reload calendarView and scroll to the current date.

Also when you have weekView, you should use a little bit different ConfigurationParameters.

That's how I do this:

```
@IBAction func monthWeekModeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        numberOfRows = 6
    } else {
        numberOfRows = 1
    }
    calendarView.reloadData()
    calendarView.scrollToDate(Date(), animateScroll: false)
}

    var numberOfRows = 6


extension CalendarViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {

func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {

    let startDate = viewModel.formatter.date(from: "01-Jan-2019")
    let endDate = viewModel.formatter.date(from: "31-Dec-2020")

    if numberOfRows == 6 {
                return ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate!, endDate: endDate!, numberOfRows: numberOfRows, firstDayOfWeek: .monday)
    } else {
        return ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate!,
                                                 endDate: endDate!,
                                                 numberOfRows: 1,
                                                 generateInDates: .forFirstMonthOnly,
                                                 generateOutDates: .off, firstDayOfWeek: .monday,
                                                 hasStrictBoundaries: false)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial [here](https://patchthecode.com/jtapplecalendar-home/week-view-month-view/) states just how to do this.

I cannot paste the whole thing here since the instructions are long.
Also, at the bottom of the page is the complete code in a zip file that you can play around with.